# How to truncate an SSAS Tabular partition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssas, tabular-model

I have a tabular cube with a large partitioned table.

I'd like to truncate some of the partitions (freeing the memory space), but retain the metadata, so that I can quickly  rebuild them if required at a later time, without having to recreate the partition.

Is this possible? If so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server Management Studio you can connect Object Explorer to SSAS, expand to the table, right click, choose Partitions, then click to process one or more partitions and do a Process Clear:

[image]